# org.eclipse.swt dependency when updating Eclipse PDT (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, eclipse-pdt

I'm trying to update Eclipse PDT on Ubuntu (through the Eclipse Interface), and I'm getting the following error:

```
Cannot complete the request.  See the details.
Cannot find a solution satisfying the following requirements org.eclipse.swt [3.4.0.v3448f].
```

This message only shows if I try to update WST Server UI (3.1.0).

AFAIK, SWT should already be there... Can anyone suggest a fix for this? I'm running Eclipse 3.4.2 and Ubuntu Jaunty (x86). I didn't install it through a package.

Comment: Remember: you can install as many eclipse as you want, and refer to the same workspace (to retrieve your environment). You just need the right eclipse.ini (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple a remarks, after reading [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.pdt/msg03915.html):

- the update mechanism p2 did improve with eclipse3.5
- you can download a ["all-in-one" PDT package here](http://eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/) (with latest WST3.1 included)

Comment: Ok so you're saying just to re-install the newer package rather than upgrade? I was trying to avoid that, but it seems that this is my only choice...